# I need a mutable version of BigInteger, but I can't access mutablebiginteger

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

I'm doing an article right now about code I wrote. I'm calculating values that go past the limit of the variable long and I also need to compare this values, so I'm using BigInteger instead.

The thing is, BigInteger is immutable so every time a new calculation happen, my program runs slower and slower cause a new BigInteger is being added in an array or something.

After some research I learned about MutableBigInteger and tried to use it, but I can't import this class because its private from java.util.Math. I found a topic where some one was using MutableBigInteger [Performance of MutableBigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888190/performance-of-mutablebiginteger)

The problem is, I couldn't understand much of his code, thus I don't know how to use an mutable version of BigInteger. I read a little about BitSet as well but I don't think it would help me in this scenario.

Imagine a clock with n numbers >0. You need to "cut" this clock in 2 (imagine a clock with 15 numbers, I'll put a risk in the number 1 and another on the number 7) now I need to check if the sum of numbers between 1 and 7 are equal to the sum between 7 and 1 (7 till n then this result 'till cut 1)

Here's my code:

```
public class LinePuzzle {
private static int tam;
private static int cont = 0;
private static int t1parte, t2parte, t3parte, t4parte, ajuda, ajuda2;


static int geraCortes(int tam) {
    Thread tt1 = new Thread(t1);
    Thread tt2 = new Thread(t2);
    Thread tt3 = new Thread(t3);
    Thread tt4 = new Thread(t4);

    if(tam % 2 == 0){ 
        ajuda = tam/4;
        t1parte = ajuda;
        t2parte = ajuda*2;
        t3parte = ajuda*3;
        t4parte = ajuda*4;
    }else{ 
        ajuda2 = tam%4;
        ajuda = (tam-ajuda2)/4;
        t1parte = ajuda;
        t2parte = (ajuda*2);
        t3parte = (ajuda*3);
        t4parte = (ajuda*4) + ajuda2;
    }

     // "Starts"
    tt1.start();
    tt2.start();
    tt3.start();
    tt4.start();

    try {
        // 
        tt1.join();
        tt2.join();
        tt3.join();
        tt4.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Finalizado");
    }
    return cont;
}

private static Runnable t1 = new Runnable()  {
@Override
public void run() {
long soma1, soma2;
    for (int i = 0; i<= t1parte; i++) { // 1º cut
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= tam; j++) { // 2º cut
            if (i == j || i == j - 1) { // tests
                continue;
            }

            soma1 = (((i + 1) + (j - 1)) * (j - i - 1)) / 2; 
            soma2 = (((j + 1) + tam) * (tam - j) + (1 + (i - 1)) * (i - 1)) / 2;

            if (soma1 == soma2 && soma1 != 0) {
                BigInteger bi, bi2; 

                bi = BigInteger.valueOf(soma1);
                bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(soma2);

                if(bi.equals(bi2)){
                System.out.printf("Equals: cut1 = %d and cut2 = %d -> result: %s / %s\n", i, j, bi, bi2);
                    cont++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};
private static Runnable t2 = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
long soma1, soma2;
    for (int i = t1parte; i<= t2parte; i++) { 
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= tam; j++) { 
            if (i == j || i == j - 1) {
                continue;
            }

            soma1 = (((i + 1) + (j - 1)) * (j - i - 1)) / 2;
            soma2 = (((j + 1) + tam) * (tam - j) + (1 + (i - 1)) * (i - 1)) / 2;

            if (soma1 == soma2 && soma1 != 0) {
               BigInteger bi, bi2; 

                bi = BigInteger.valueOf(soma1);
                bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(soma2);

                if(bi.equals(bi2)){
                System.out.printf("Equals: cut1 = %d and cut2 = %d -> result: %s / %s\n", i, j, bi, bi2);
                    cont++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};

private static Runnable t3 = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
long soma1, soma2;
    for (int i = t2parte; i<= t3parte; i++) { // 1º corte
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= tam; j++) { // 2º corte
            if (i == j || i == j - 1) {
                continue;
            }

            soma1 = (((i + 1) + (j - 1)) * (j - i - 1)) / 2;
            soma2 = (((j + 1) + tam) * (tam - j) + (1 + (i - 1)) * (i - 1)) / 2;

            if (soma1 == soma2 && soma1 != 0) {
                BigInteger bi, bi2; 

                bi = BigInteger.valueOf(soma1);
                bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(soma2);
                if(bi.equals(bi2)){
                System.out.printf("Equals: cut1 = %d and cut2 = %d -> result: %s / %s\n", i, j, bi, bi2);
                    cont++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
};

private static Runnable t4 = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
long soma1, soma2;
    for (int i = t3parte; i<= t4parte; i++) { // 1º corte
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= tam; j++) { // 2º corte
            if (i == j || i == j - 1) {
                continue;
            }

            soma1 = (((i + 1) + (j - 1)) * (j - i - 1)) / 2;
            soma2 = (((j + 1) + tam) * (tam - j) + (1 + (i - 1)) * (i - 1)) / 2;

            if (soma1 == soma2 && soma1 != 0) {
                BigInteger bi, bi2; 

                bi = BigInteger.valueOf(soma1);
                bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(soma2);
                if(bi.equals(bi2)){
                System.out.printf("Equals: cut1 = %d and cut2 = %d -> result: %s / %s\n", i, j, bi, bi2);
                    cont++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("Clock length: ");
        tam = scan.nextInt();
    }while(tam < 2);

    System.out.println("Numbers of equals: " + geraCortes(tam)); // executar o geracortes e os threads
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `Integer.toString` in your code? That is very inefficient. Use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` instead. That would probably already help a lot with performance. Also given you're using integers as base values, I'm wondering if you can't simply use `long` for your calculations (the calculations as shown won't overflow). You might also want to consider creating a constant for that `new BigInteger("2")` (or if you're using Java 9 or higher: `BigInteger.TWO`).

Comment: This seems like a classical XY problem - have you really confirmed that immutability is causing the performance issues? The problem description is so vague (”is being added in an array or something”) so I rather doubt it.

Comment: prior to this version I wasn't using BigInteger, which was causing numbers to return negative and also the number of comparisons was wrong. When I implemented BigInteger and compared the numbers again, the performance drop down a lot but now I was getting the right results. I think the biginteger is indeedslowing down my program. Btw I'm trying to implemente the solution Mark Rotteveel mentioned

Comment: Ok, I missed that the second line had two multiply operations, which can indeed cause an overflow. In the future, consider formatting code so it is all visible without scrolling. In any case, you could change parts of your code to first do as much as possible with long, and only when overflow will happen, switch to BigInteger.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I used BigInteger.valueOf()  but i'm getting overflowed results... I'll post my code and describe what it needs to do in a description

Comment: please note than all your `i+1`, `j-1` can owerflow too

Comment: If you get overflows when using `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`, then you should also be getting overflows with your current solution; or you're relying on an existing overflow that no longer occurs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this code is actually a nightmare, every time I think i'm close to a solution a new problem appears and I don't know what to do

Comment: @yunandtidus so you're saying the i of my for can overflow?

Comment: if `i == Long.MAX_VALUE`, then yes

Comment: @yunandtidus my teacher said that 500000 would be the limit to n, so I think int is okay. My bad, should've mentioned it

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how to use BigInteger to make calculations.

Below are examples with two of your calculations (assuming `i`, `j`, `tam` are longs):

```
//(((i + 1) + (j - 1)) * (j - i - 1)) / 2; 
BigInteger bSoma1 = bigI.add(BigInteger.ONE)
        .add(bigJ.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))
        .multiply(bigJ.subtract(bigI).subtract(BigInteger.ONE))
        .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

//(((j + 1) + tam) * (tam - j) + (1 + (i - 1)) * (i - 1)) / 2;
BigInteger bSoma2 = bigJ.add(BigInteger.ONE).add(bigTam)
        .multiply(bigTam.subtract(bigJ))
        .add(BigInteger.ONE.add(bigI.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)))
        .multiply(bigI.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))
        .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
```

Comment: @yunadtidus This was really helpful, thank you. A friend of mine told me about biginteger and he taught me how to use, since he's way smarter than me I thought this was the only way